# MacBook Pro (2018) display error

Tags: macbook-pro, display, catalina

From last Monday I have this display issue:

[image]

- MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2018, Four Thundebolt 3 Ports)
- Intel Iris Plus Graphics 655 1536 MB
- macOS Catalina 10.15.3

[image]

Tried all the reset recommendations but no effect.

What's interesting is that these lines track graphical elements and widgets in the user interface, for example when scrolling a web page.

On an external monitor, there are no such occurrences.

Is there any fix for this?

Comment: Most likely it's a display issue.  To be certain it's the display and not the GPU, take a screenshot.  See if those artifacts remain

Comment: no bugs on screenshout

Comment: It's your display or your display cable.  You can further confirm by hooking up an external display, but either way, it's got to go in for repairs.

Comment: do the "reset recommendations" include reinstalling macOS?

Comment: @ProkopHanzl yes now, but without effect.